# Consigo executar o código localnente, mas no Heroku não

Tags: node.js, heroku, https

Quando executo esse código localmente tudo ocorre bem, e é retornada a página do Instagram. Porém, quando eu fiz deploy para o Heroku eu não consigo mais executar o código, pois um erro aparece. Já tentei mudar a versão do Node no Heroku, colocando exatamente a mesma que eu usei para rodar o código no PC mas nada adiantou.

```
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
/* Create the base function to be ran */
const start = async () => {
    /* Here you replace the username with your actual instagram username that you want to check */
    const USERNAME = 'doarda';
    const BASE_URL = `https://www.instagram.com/${USERNAME}/`;
    /* Send the request and get the html content */
    let response = await request(
        BASE_URL,
        {
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,fr;q=0.8,ro;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6,la;q=0.5,pt;q=0.4,de;q=0.3',
            'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
        }
    );
    
    /* Initiate Cheerio with the response */
    let $ = cheerio.load(response);
    
    /* Get the proper script of the html page which contains the json */
    let script = $('script').eq(4).html();
    console.log(script)
    /* Traverse through the JSON of instagram response */
    let { entry_data: { ProfilePage : {[0] : { graphql : {user} }} } } = JSON.parse(/window\._sharedData = (.+);/g.exec(script)[1]);
    
    /* Output the data */
    console.log(user);
    debugger;
}

start()
```

O erro que recebo no Heroku é este

```
2020-10-17T01:11:47.767189+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
2020-10-17T01:11:47.767190+00:00 app[worker.1]: at start (/app/igbot.js:28:128)
2020-10-17T01:11:47.767273+00:00 app[worker.1]: (node:4) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
```

Alguma ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Pelo `console.log(script)` você provavelmente verá que o log local é diferente do servidor, ao executar `g.exec(script)` retorna nulo, e, ao tentar acessar a propriedade/índice `1`, causa o erro

Comment: então, mas o que causa essa diferença? alguma ideia de por que localmente eu consigo executar, mas no heroku não?